# What does this triangle pointing right symbol mean?

Tags: notation

In the third step below, what does the little triangle pointing right mean?

> Sum of roots: \begin{align}\alpha+\beta&=-\frac 53 \cdots \tag{1}\\[6pt]
> \alpha-\beta&=\frac 73\cdots \tag{2}\end{align}
>
> $(1)+(2)$: \begin{align}2\alpha&=\frac 23\\[6pt]
> \alpha&=\frac 13\cdots\tag{3}\end{align}
>
> $(3) \triangleright(1)$:
>
> \begin{align}\left(\frac 13\right)^2+5\left(\frac 13\right)+k&=0\\
> k&=-2\end{align}

Comment: Contextually, "three substituted into one"...  But it seems that they skipped solving for $\beta$ and moved on to identifying the constant term of a quadratic...